# Advagg css files are refering old site address

Tags: css-js-aggregation

i have developed site in one machine (www.example.com). i moved all setup to another machine (www.example1.com).after moving some problem is there.some css files like "css__48K1J5D3tG5zmBfajwIKY-4DGflacHFmJ6qlkBqjtPw__hdw......css" under advagg_css folder refering old site url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your site is trying to reference CSS that was held in your 'files' folder that may not now exist.

If you navigate to configuration > Performance

and untick 'Aggregate and compress CSS files'

> Save Configuration
>
> Clear Caches.

Now check your site and see if it works.  If it does you should be able to reenable the compression and hopefully your site will work fine.